# error: cannot find symbol import dagger.hilt.android.components.ApplicationComponent;

Tags: android, multi-module, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to include dagger hilt to my multimodule project with just three modules (app, frameworks_and_drivers, interface_adapters). I followed the hilt documentation https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android?hl=es-419, so i ended addding the same things to the three different modules, i know we can sinplify to just add in a single one. When i tried to rebuild the project this error appear: "**error: cannot find symbol
import dagger.hilt.android.components.ApplicationComponent**;" [image]

for some reason the ApplicationComponent is not available even when the other are.

[image]

Maybe if one of you know how to fix this, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

from `2.33-beta` there is no ApplicationComponent, you will have to use SingletonComponent. [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) is here.

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround updating the hilt version in build.gradle (Project) **`classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.31.2-alpha'`** and updating also the dependencies on build.gralde (your_module) **"

```
// DI with Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.31.2-alpha"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03
```

'"**
This is the video that helped to me with this: https://youtu.be/9ZnzmbClarw

Comment: it worked for me after updating all dependencies version to latest version . update both `Project Gradle` and `Module Gradle` file. get latest version from here https://dagger.dev/hilt/gradle-setup.html